# Looking for an invariant similar to algebraic K-theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, infinity-categories

I'm wondering if there is an invariant, similar to algebraic K-theory, topological hochshild homologic, topological cyclic homology etc... that has the following properties:

**a)** It attach to each small stable $\infty$-category $A$ a spectrum $E(A)$.

**b)** Its functorial on exact functor.

**c)** It satisfies an additivity property similar to that of $K$-theory, $THH$, i.e. at the minimum it sends split exact sequence of small stable $\infty$-category to (split) cofiber sequences. (so essentially it is an "additive invariant" in the sense of [Blumberg, Gepner, Tabuada](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.2282.pdf))

**d)** For each object $a \in A$, there is an element $\chi(a) \in E(A)$ that is natural and behave additively on cofiber sequence, (so more formally, there is a natural transformation $K(A) \to E(A)$

**e)** If $X$ is a space (an $\infty$-groupoid), and $Sp^X$ denotes the full subcategory of compact object in  the infinity category $Sh(X,Sp)$ of (locally constant) sheaves of spectrum on $X$, then:

$$E(Sp^X) \simeq \Sigma^\infty_+ X$$ is the suspension spectrum of $X$. Where the identification is functorial in $X$. I would also be happy if $E(Sp^X)$ gives the homology of $X$ instead, but the former would be more general.

Both $K$-theory, $THH$ and $TC$ have all these properties excepte maybe $(e)$. $THH$ fall close with $THH(Sp^X) \simeq \Sigma^\infty_+ \left( X^{S^1} \right)$.

I don't know well enough $TC$ and its variant to know directly if one them has property $(e)$. If it the case I would be very happy with a reference that proves it. Otherwise I'm hoping that some kind of "simplified K-theory" will do the trick, maybe a quotient of $K$-theory, but I don't know these topics well enough to figure it out.

**Motivation:** Let $I$ and $J$ be two *finite direct* (1-)categories. I denote by $\widehat{I}$ and $\widehat{J}$ the $\infty$-categories of presheaves of $\infty$-groupoids on them.

Given $F: \widehat{J} \to \widehat{J}$ a left adjoint functor preserving finitely presented objects, we can define a linear map:
$$ |F| : \bigoplus_{i \in Ob(I)} \mathbb{Z} \to \bigoplus_{j \in Ob(J)} \mathbb{Z}$$

that "computes" the levelwise Euler characteristic of $F(X)$ from the levelwise Euler characteristic of $X$, when $X$ is a finitely presentable objects in $\widehat{I}$, in the sense that:

$$ \chi(X(i)) \in \bigoplus_{i \in Ob(I)} \mathbb{Z} \mapsto \chi(F(X)(j)) \in \bigoplus_{j \in Ob(j)}$$

This construction is quite useful when studying for example nice monads on such presheaf categories: it attach easy to compute and quite subtle numerical invariant to certain nice finitary functors.

I would like to upgrade this, by replacing abelian group by connective spectra and allowing $I$ and $J$ to be more general $\infty$-categories, but I'm struggling in proving that what I want to construct has the appropriate functorialy properties.

I realized at some point that functor above could be interpreted as:

$$ \pi_0 THH( Sp^{I^{op}}) = \bigoplus_{i \in I} \mathbb{Z} $$

where $Sp^{I^{op}}$ denotes the category of compact presheaves of spectrum on $I$. Indeed using additivity of $THH$, we can show by induction on height that:

$$ THH( Sp^{I^{op}}) = \Sigma_\infty^+ \left( Ob(I) \right)$$

To some extent taking $THH$ actually is "good enough" for most of the applications I have in mind. But it does not behave quite as I would like, and this makes everything more complicated. Typically, when $I$ is a generalized direct $\infty$-category (that is it can have some automorphisms) satisfying some finiteness condition I won't go into, I would like the invariant to be:

$$ \Sigma^\infty_+ ( core(I)) $$

where $core$ denotes the maximal sub $\infty$-groupoid. While, induction on height gives:

$$THH(Sp^{I^{op}}) = \Sigma^\infty_+ ( core(I)^{S^1}) $$

This of course is exactly because (e) fails for THH. But on the other hand, when I consider the example I'm interested in, it seems consistant that one could get rid of this $S^1$ : The way it appears in THH is because THH is the target of the universal trace map, and an endomorphism in $Sp^{I^{op}}$ can be over automorphisms of $I$ and hence remember a "loop" in $I$, but I' only interested in "characteristic of objects" (see point (d)) not trace of maps, so this "circle" is not relevant for me. So I'm hoping there is a different invariant from THH that would get rid of it.

I started studying the alternative (K-theory, TC etc...) but couldn't really decide if one of them was solving my problem... K-theory do not have this circle showing up, but lots of additional things, that are not relevant to me, (basicaly the K-theory of the point) comes up. And for TC (and its negative or periodic variant), I haven't been be able to understand how it behaves on spaces. I'm hoping an expert on the topic can point me to the right direction...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the definition of $|F|$. Could you elaborate? The natural analogue of $\bigoplus_{i\in\mathrm{ob}I}\mathbb{Z}$ would seem to me $\mathcal{C}\mapsto \Sigma^\infty_+(\mathcal{C})$, but that is well known not to be an additive invariant (and indeed its additive approximation is K-theory), and moreover does not have the result you wish on categories of sheaves.

Comment: @DenisNardin : I've added lots of details to the "motivation" part". Note that I'm not expecting to obtain $\Sigma^\infty_+ core(C)$ for all all $\infty$-categories $C$, only well behaved one (typically generalized direct categories).

Comment: Also the concrete definition of $|F|$ I know of is complicated and involves some some combinatorics. But at the end it can be characterized by the fact that it computes Euler characteristic as explained above.

Comment: Let me delete those comments and start again. Do you really need such an abstract and general construction? Do you have an example of something you would detect? I assume by sheaves you mean locally constant sheaves. (If not, factor through them.) Take the fiber / skyscraper adjunction $C\rightleftharpoons Sh(X;C)$. This is parameterized by the space of points, so you get $X\wedge K(C)\to K(Sh(X;C))$ and $K(Sh(X;C))\to Hom(X,K(C))$. I guess the first is the assembly map. I like [Dwyer-Weiss-Williams](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485891548), but I'm not sure how relevant it is.

Comment: @BenWieland : I do not need the full generality explained in the first part of the question. But I need a construction that applies to the category of presheaf of spectra on a generlaized direct category. what I'm really after is to extend the functor $I \mapsto \Sigma^\infty_+ Core(I)$ (for $I$ generalized direct category satisfying some finiteness condition), so that it becomes functorial with respect to profunctors (satisfying finiteness conditions).

Comment: ... I sould add: In the same way that taking THH makes functorial on profunctors the construction $I \mapsto \Sigma^\infty_+ (Core(I)^{S^1})$ (also for $I$ a generalized direct category, satisfying some finiteness conditions, and only for profunctors satisfying some finiteness conditions)